# How to rewrite & redirect nonsecure image urls from any subdomain through local https proxy using Url rewrite and IIS 8.5?

Tags: redirect, proxy, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module, iis-8.5

I am trying to **redirect/redirect and pass all http-only (non-secure) image urls through a local https proxy hosted on my domain** (using Url Rewrite in IIS 8.5). The source does not provide https so this is my only solution (as far as I know). Here is my code and its not working. Kindly help:

```
<rule name="assets redirection" stopProcessing="false">
        <match url="^(.*)\.example-differnt-domain\.com" ignoreCase="false" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.COM/p/?url={HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" 
        appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

It does not seem to be doing anything.
Source images urls are in the following format

**`http://subdomain1.subdomain2.example-different-domain.com/xyz/abc/lmnop.jpg`**

There could be other image types too

I want to rewrite the url so that it looks like this:
**`https://example.COM/p/?url=http://subdomain1.subdomain2.example-different-domain.com/xyz/abc/lmnop.jpg`**

Unfortunately, my regex is not really good and i am wondering I am might be doing something wrong with the pattern matching.

Any help is appreciated in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

The url attribute in the match node only matches the path, not the domain. In order to match the host you will need to use the HTTP_HOST server variable. [This](https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Accessing_URL_Parts_from_a_Rewrite_Rule) section of the rewrite rule documentation give a good explanation of this. There are a couple of examples as well on that page that use HTTP_HOST which seems similar to what you are trying to achieve.